# OrientDB Studio - How to display Embedded Field Values?

Tags: orientdb

Is there any way to make OrientDB Studio display embedded field values inside the graph?

For example, I want to show the *name.en* values for from the following class...

```
@class 

**Items**

name: {"de":"Deutsch","en":"English"}
```

Comment: http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

From the Graph view, select a node and it'll make appear its Settings tab at the left of the page, then just select your field from the Display list.

Comment: This does not work for embedded fields. If I select my embedded field **name** from the given sample class above, the graph only shows `[object Object]` as value.